# Error in "missforest" in R

Tags: r, imputation

Need help to get around the below error while performing data imputation in R using "missforest" package.

```
> imputed<- missForest(dummy, maxiter = 10, ntree = 100, variablewise = TRUE,
+                      decreasing = TRUE, verbose = TRUE,
+                      mtry = floor(sqrt(ncol(dummy))), replace = TRUE)
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. Transforming xmis object with as.data.frame helped. In your case it would be something like:

```
dummy <- as.data.frame(dummy)    
imputed<- missForest(dummy, maxiter = 10, ntree = 100, variablewise = TRUE,
                      decreasing = TRUE, verbose = TRUE,
                      mtry = floor(sqrt(ncol(dummy))), replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: I thought of that and did that. Even then I faced the issue. Anything else that might be causing the error.

Comment: What is the class of dummy in your case?

Comment: > class(dummy)
[1] "data.frame"

Comment: I removed the "attributes" of each column (e.g., labels)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others, `missForest()` requires input data to be of class *data.frame* or *matrix*. If, like many people, you imported or manipulated your data using functions of the `tidyverse` packages, then your dataset is likely to be a **tibble** (class *tbl_df*) and will thus need to be converted with `as.data.frame()` before imputing the missing values.
As OP said that his/her data were contained in a *data.frame*, the problem perhaps comes from the class of the variables. According to [this page](https://github.com/stekhoven/missForest/issues/19#issuecomment-612661181), the same error message can appear if you have **date variables** (class *date* or *difftime*). Be sure to work with *numeric* or *factor* variables only.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using fread() to read the data, try using read.csv() instead. I had the same problem while using fread() to read the data, even after converting the data.table to data.frame by using as.data.frame() later. But, later I read the data by using read.csv and the problem got solved.